# Rails upgrade doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10. When I run rails -v, I get 2.3.5. I want to upgrade to 3.0.5, so I run sudo gem install rails.  I get

```
Successfully installed rails-3.0.5
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.0.5...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.0.5...
```

I run rails -v again. It still returns 2.3.5. I run sudo apt-get install rails, I get

```
Reading state information... Done
rails is already the newest version.
```

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try `sudo rails -v` and see if you're getting the latest version. Looks like your superuser's rails and the your user account rails are different.

Comment: Try `rails _3.0.5_`. Since you used the `install` command, it has installed 2 versions. You want to use the `gem update` command.

Comment: i ran sudo gem update rails _3.0.5_, it says there's nothing to update.

Comment: I meant try `rails _3.0.5_ -v`. Furthermore, if you wanted to update rails, you should have used the `gem update rails` command.

Comment: Combining distribution packaging tools and language packaging tools usually leads to tears. You might want to `apt-get remove rails` and rely on the `gem`-supplied packages, if that's really the route you wish to take.

Comment: I did sudo apt-get remove rails, it worked. Then i ran sudo gem install rails, and that says rails 3.0.5. has been installed. But then when I run rails -v, I get bash: /usr/bin/rails: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your current gemfile, probably it has record only for rails 2.3.5, if it does then change to 3.0.5. After this just run `bundle install`